# Can I get onBackPressed event inside a custom ViewGroup?

Tags: android, android-layout, custom-component

I am creating a custom Android component that needs sometimes to consume the onBackPressed event (e.g. there's a popup menu inside the custom ViewGroup, if it's showing, the back button event closes it and is consumed, otherwise it's ignored). Is that possible? Can I intercept this event from inside my ViewGroup subclass and how?

Edit:
I tried overriding onKeyPreIme as the Android documentation implies, the method is never invoked from within ViewGroup.

```
@Override
public boolean onKeyPreIme(int keyCode, KeyEvent event)
{
     return true;
}
```

In the **onKeyPreIme** documentation it says:

> **Handle a key event before it is processed by any input method associated with the view      hierarchy. This can be used to intercept key events in special situations before the IME consumes them; a typical example would be handling the BACK key to update the application's UI instead of allowing the IME to see it and close itself.**

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The reason why onKeyDown or onKeyPreIme are never invoked is because the ViewGroup does not have focus.

The solution was to request focus in the ViewGroup subclass' constructor:

```
this.setFocusable(true);
this.setFocusableInTouchMode(true);
this.requestFocus();
```

Answer (score 2):

**onBackPressed** belongs to Activity and views/viewgroups are something placed inside Activity. So technically, you cant get this done. However, you may use some kind of *[**observer/observable**](http://www.javaworld.com/jw-10-1996/jw-10-howto.html)* pattern to pass any kind of information to your views.

Or perhaps try using **[onKeyDown](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#onKeyDown%28int,%20android.view.KeyEvent%29)** event inside your view class and track the [**back key**](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/KeyEvent.html#KEYCODE_BACK) event code.

Comment: onKeyDown event is never invoked from inside the ViewGroup subclass. As for the observer/observable, it will require that I manually pass the event from inside my activity which looks like a hack to me. I want the ViewGroup subclass to intercept the event without my intervention. Is it possible?

Comment: if onKeyDown isn't working in your case (which I doubted too), so I guess observer/observable pattern is the only best option available in my mind. However, you may also try defining a custom method in your viewgroup class and call this method from your activity class inside onBackKeyPressed event. This is somehow helpful to skip observer/observable pattern in case you dont want your code to look fancy and support multiple other calls in future :)